# Read Values from xml file

Tags: asp-classic

I have a function TRANSLATE which reads value from the xml file based on a key. I wanna put
"**http://www.google.com?search=**" in the xml file and read it based on the key(**SEARCHER**)

I am confused in framing the link when it comes in Response.Write

```
<%Dim SearchQuery1
 SearchQuery1="New"
 Dim SearchQuery2
 SearchQuery2=30

Response.Write("<A HREF=""http://www.google.com?search="&SearchQuery1&"-"&SearchQuery2&""" TARGET=""links"">http://www.google.com?search="&SearchQuery1&"-"&SearchQuery2&"</A>")
%>
```

I was trying something like this

```
Response.Write("<A HREF=""Translate("SEARCHER")"&SearchQuery1&"-"&SearchQuery2&""" TARGET=""links"">Translate("SEARCHER")"&SearchQuery1&"-"&SearchQuery2&"</A>")
```

but is throwing some error: Expected)'

PLs let me know how can i solve this????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have found the solution yourself, but for future reference this is the correct syntax

```
Response.Write( "<A HREF=""" & Translate(SEARCHER) & SearchQuery1 & "-" & SearchQuery2 & """ TARGET=""links"">" & Translate(SEARCHER) & SearchQuery1 & "-" & SearchQuery2 & "</A>")
```